# Making a table with cols

Tags: multicolumn

Right now I am doing something like:

```
\twocolumn
{\footnotesize
\begin{center}
    \tablehead{$x$ & $y$ \\ \hline}
    \begin{supertabular}{ccc}
        entry_x & entry_y \\
        etc
```

Is there a way to do this over a few columns?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish other than saying "this"?

Comment: you can use package `multicol` but you have to do the column breaks by hand: closing and restarting the supertabular.

Comment: use `\begin{multicols}{3}` (without the `\twocolumn`), then set the complete supertabular. Have a look where a columnbreak makes sense and insert `\end{supertabular} \begin{supertabular}{ccc}` ... `\end{multicols}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{supertabular,multicol}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\tablehead{$x$ & $y$ \\ \hline}
\begin{supertabular}{ccc}
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
\end{supertabular}
\columnbreak
\par
\begin{supertabular}{ccc}
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
\end{supertabular}
\columnbreak
\par
\begin{supertabular}{ccc}
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
  entry\_x & entry\_y \\
\end{supertabular}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put a blank line before each `\columnbreak`. Without it, that break is placed *after the current line*, which would seem to be (sometimes) after one of the following `supertabular` environments. Then you get (sometimes) two `supertabular`s side-by-side in one column and one in the other.